# How can i change value of JavaScript variable using If Statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple forms in same php page. I am able to show and hide them based the drop down value selected But I have a variable called `$url` i want to have different value when each form loads

```
     <script>
      function validate(){
      var first = document.getElementById("first");
      var first-val = first.options[first.selectedIndex].value;
      var second = document.getElementById("seconed");
      var secondval = second.options[second.selectedIndex].value;

if(first-val == "Rear Tire" && secondval ==  "2WD")
{
document.getElementById("RA").style.display="";
document.getElementById("RB").style.display="none";
 var test = '<?php $url ="reartire"?>
} 

else if(first-val == "Rear Tire" && secondval ==  "MFWD")
   {
    document.getElementById("RA").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("RB").style.display="";
   var test = '<?php $url ="fronttire"?>
   }
```

I tried adding

Inside the the first `if` - `var test = '<?php $url ="yahoo.com"?>';`

For the second if i added `if`- `var test = '<?php $url ="google.com"?>';` But it only sees the the value of `$url` inside the second `if`

Comment: What does the title mean? Using what?

Comment: There are some serious grammatical issues in this question. Did you run this through google translate? That doesn't work. Furthermore you can't mix and match the `$url=`. It's going to assign that regardless of whether or not it hits the conditional, because PHP interprets the page top down.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry for the grammer and Typo. thanks. what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: `$url` is a PHP variable, not a JavaScript variable.

Comment: var test = '<?php $url ="reartire"?>  <---You're missing a single quote and a semicolon here as well.  var test = '<?php $url ="fronttire"?>  <---And here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in the value assignment of test in js using php. Either use php short tag or echo the php variable when assigning php variable/value to a js variable.